# How to delete files using the right-aws gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, right-aws

I need to find out how to delet a file on my S3 bucket using the right-aws gem (https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws). The current doc (the README at github) isn't very helpful...

Has anyone tried doing something similar and would like to share their findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RightAws::S3::Key have a method called delete. [Click here for documentation](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/right_aws_gem_doc/).

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get it to work with: s3 = RightAws::S3.new(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key); bucket = s3.bucket('bucket_name'); bucket.delete_folder('uploads/users/1/video/1')

Comment: Deleting via folder can be little risky if you have two keys uploads/users/1/video/1, uploads/users/1/video/1/123. You need to make sure that you have no such case.

Comment: I told that in my answer. key1 = RightAws::S3::Key.create(bucket, 'uploads/users/1/video/1'); key1.delete()

Comment: I don't think delete() removes folders... I think delete is used more for individual files. Correct me if I am wrong. I have tried this, but it doesn't seem like it is removing the folder

Comment: key1 = RightAws::S3::Key.create(bucket, 'uploads/users/1/video/1'); key1.delete() will delete only individual files. What I means was delete_folder on bucket deletes folders as name suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The best is [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Doesn't AWS:S3 have some issues? Could be the same reason why Carrierwave moved from this gem to right_aws? Could be wrong here...

Comment: It seems that the appoxy/aws is now the one to use. Right_aws is now called simply aws, and you install it by typing 'gem install aws'

https://rubygems.org/gems/aws

Comment: Oops - I now its altogether more complicated... It seems that right_aws is alive and well on its own. Don't know how to pick one..

Answer (score 1):

With the newly released aws-sdk gem you can delete a file like so:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => '...', :secret_access_key => '...')
s3.buckets['YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'].objects['OBJECT_KEY'].delete
```